# How to get view depend on user in sap UI5?

Tags: sapui5

How should I project my application to get contexts based on logged user in sapUI5? I was thinking about providing this information by oData service, is this a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you use the launchpad:**
If you want to provide the same application in different forms, you could give users different roles and start the APP with different StartUp parameters: [Handling Startup Parameters](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/07/9561b716bb4f2f8ae4e47bacbdb86d/content.htm?no_cache=true)

[Startup Parameters in Launchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTies.png)

Then all you have to do is, to check the parameters and display the APP differently.

Comment: Thanks ! But what about standalone app, which is not uploaded into the ABAP stack or SCP ? Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: i think, as you already said, the best way would be via an oData service and storing the information in backend